# How to add progressbar column in DataGridView in C# (Winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Is there any way so that I add a progress bar column in datagridview.
Actually I need to show the progress for each rows (task) in the datagridview.

Let me know some sample code or links to acheive this functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/769ca9d6-1e9d-4d76-8c23-db535b2f19c2) MSDN post that has sample code inside.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
int percent = (int)(((double)progressBar1.Value / (double)progressBar1.Maximum) * 100);

progressBar1.CreateGraphics().DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - 10, progressBar1.Height / 2 - 7));
```

this is the code for progress bar.. check out

Comment: Downvoted as this doesn't answer the question at all. I don't understand why it was accepted.

Comment: this answer is for "how do I put a label on a progress bar", nothing to do with datagrids